# How do I install these Coda mode files hosted on github? (I followed the instructions but no joy)

Tags: file, github, mode, coda

The mode files for Coda.app (for syntax highlighting etc etc) hosted at rolling address come with these instructions. I enter the line in terminal and hit return but nothing seemed to get created. I was logged into github in Safari with my account. I haven't used github so I don't know much about it other that it's a web based version control system that all the cool kids use.

https://github.com/bobthecow/coda-modes#readme

### readme:

> Syntax modes for Coda and SubEthaEdit
>   A selection of syntax modes for for Coda (and SubEthaEdit) curated by bobthecow.
>
> Installation
>   If you already have a folder at ~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes move it (or remove it if it's empty).
>   Check out this repository:
>
> cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Coda git clone --recursive git://github.com/bobthecow/coda-modes.git Modes
>   If you have additional syntax modes in your old Modes folder, copy them into this folder.
>   Restart Coda.

Comment: If you have any specific error message for those commands, please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, those are supposed to be *two* command lines here:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Coda
git clone --recursive git://github.com/bobthecow/coda-modes.git Modes
```

This should create a "Modes" directory within "`~/Library/Application\ Support/Coda`".

If the git address doesn't work, try the htts one:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/bobthecow/coda-modes.git Modes
```

Note that a [`git clone --recursive`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clone.html) initializes all submodules within, using their default settings. This is equivalent to running `git submodule update --init --recursive` immediately after the clone is finished.

Comment: `git clone --recursive` means git1.6.5+ (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.5.txt). Make sure you are using a recent git version (ie later than September 2010).

Comment: I'm a newb and so while I suspected it was two lines I didn't realise I needed to install git myself (not preinstalled as part of OS X) so that's my first step... reading the git book/docs now... back for to this task tomorrow. Thanks for advice VonC.